# SQLPlus using at notation @ in a String

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to use to insert a string that has an @ notation in sqlplus, but sqlplus reads the string like i am trying to open an .sql file. Is there a way to stop sqlplus from doing that.

ex

```
set define off;
DECLARE
   test CLOB
         := q'[

 @font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;
    panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */ ]' ;


BEGIN

INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE
VALUES(test)


END;
/
```

Comment: Is there a way to change restriction level to level 3 through a script? that way it disbales the start command. then set the restrictions back to default?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used Oracles Quote operator: `q'[""]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use sql variables.

```
variable var VARCHAR(20);
SQL> select "@!$$" into :var  from dual;

SQL> select *
  2    from some_table
  3   where some_table_name = :var;
```

in your :var you can make the string you want to insert

```
insert into some_table values (':var {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}')
```

Comment: I updated my code. I need something that does this all in one script. without having to modify it the original text.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I don't have this issue in sqlplus (SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create table tmp1(x varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tmp1 values ('@font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:
2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}');

1 row created.
```

You can set an escape character:

```
SQL> set escape '\';
SQL> insert into tmp1 values ('\@456');

1 row created.
```

This will insert @456

Comment: I updated my code to a more accurate sample of what i am trying to do. I need something that does this all in one script. without having to modify it the original text

Comment: @tbone - SQLPlus does have some weird parsing issues.  For example, try creating a string with only the character "/" on the line and it will break the anonymous block.  However, I can't reproduce this exact issue either.  Jeff - can you include the SQL*Plus and OS version?  This may be a platform-specific bug.

Comment: sqlplus 10.2.0.1.0 and win 8.1. which versions are you running.

Comment: @JonHeller Yes, I agree, SQLPlus can be a bit picky at times.  But we may find that he's using Oracle 7 ;)

Comment: is there a way to escape that character through scripts without having to go back into notepad and edit the file. I use toad, but i have to make sure it'll run in any enviornment

Comment: @JeffGarcia Do you mean you're running it in SQLPlus through Toad instead of the command line SQLPlus?

Comment: sorry, i use toad as my primary, then i test on sqlplus via command line to make sure that a dba can run my script.

Comment: i upgraded to 11.2.0.1.0 and the error is still present. any suggestions to get around it?